# Delete data from multible tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables say table X and table Y.
I want to delete all data from table X with column value = x1 and also want to delete data from table Y with column value = x1.

How can i achieve this using a single `Delete` statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to delete from multiple tables, you should specify the table you want to delete so you will not get syntax error.

```
DELETE x, y
FROM   x INNER JOIN y ON x.Col = y.Col
WHERE  x.Col = 'x1'
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00ab7/1

Answer (score 1):

```
delete x,y from x,y where x.colname='x1' and y.colname='x1'
```

Try this query.

Hope its helpful.

Comment: you need to specify the target tables since you are deleting from multiple tables.

Comment: @JW User has said target table names as x and y

Comment: @JW but when i executes this as delete from tablename in sqlserver without specifying column name, it does not gives me error.

Comment: oh it's sql server 2008 now. you cannot delete values from multiple tables using single delete statement. you can join but can only delete from one table.

Comment: @JW ok. Might be with sql server 2008, i dont know. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Use multiple DELETE statement.
2. Use foreign key's feature for related InnoDb tables - **ON DELETE CASCADE** action to remove data from tables. In this case it is enough to delete data from parent table, all related records in child tables will be deleted automatically.